# StackExchange drop down menu is confusing

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange-button

The StackExchange drop down menu confuses me. Sometimes I get the drop-down and sometimes it goes to the stackexchange.com homepage.

Is it an issue or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the JavaScript hasn't yet loaded, it functions as a normal link. After the JavaScript loads, it functions as a dropdown.

I find this happens when i have a slow connection and the page, and by extension, scripts, don't load fast enough.

Comment: Everything else loads fast for me. It seems like the script is simply not loading for some reason.